# Console.ReadLine activating prematurely

Tags: c#

I've been trying to figure this out for dozens of tries, but I can't seem to understand why this line executes?

> Console.WriteLine("please enter a number.");

I get it on the screen even before I enter any character as input. 
any help is appreciated

```
int numberAsInt;
while (true) {
    try {
        numberAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        break;
    }
    catch {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] (you sort of have) and *data necessary to reproduce the issue* - clearly you are reading value that you don't expect - debugging should reveal it (normally you'd read into variable first so it is easier to see exact value...)

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. This question has everything needed - I'm baffled as well why though, works on my machine just fine...

Comment: Well for one, we can't tell if your actually entering a number. Whats the code above it

Comment: Do you hit any keys after starting the program?

Comment: As others have said debug into the problem. Add `string enteredValue = Console.ReadLine();` before the conversion, and debug to see if what you're entering is really a number, then try the conversion. Your code works fine if the value supplied is really a number.

Comment: Do you mean that the `Console.WriteLine` line executes before you do the `Console.Readline`?

Comment: Please use the catch clause to print out the exception message, then post the exception message. Please also catch the input from the console into a string variable and use the debugger to find out what value this variable has

Comment: Always, always use `catch (Exception ex) { ... }` so you can see what exception is being thrown. You could easily know what happened if you weren't trying so hard not to find out. You may feel like you've "been trying to figure this out", but I think you've just been staring helplessly at the screen, because you don't seem to have made any effort to gather any information about what happened. If nobody ever told you how, that's fair enough -- but now you know.

Comment: The root issue is NOT the exception.. it is that Console.ReadLine will accept input even before you think it is. Pulling back exception info would not help identify the root issue here more than what is already known (as evidenced by "I get on the screen even before I enter any character input").

Answer (score 3):

The reason the catch block fired is that there is an exception caused by:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

The `ReadLine()` method will read whatever you have already entered -- even if there is nothing.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

> [Returns] the next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available.
>
> If the standard input device is the keyboard, the ReadLine method blocks until the user presses the Enter key.

Comment: Was able to duplicate on my machine and verify this answer. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use try/catch to check your input. Better way:

```
int numberAsInt;
while (true) {
    String str = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(str, out numberAsInt)) {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("please enter a number.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of an infinite `while` loop and a `try/catch` block to verify if the user entered a valid number, you can use [**`int.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
int num;
string input = "";

while (!int.TryParse(input, out num))
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number:");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Number entered:" + num);
```

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on [Emerson Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492993/2658159), the reason why is because Console.Readline will pull back information from the Console... which runs outside of your code logic.

This means that it doesn't wait until you type `Console.Readline()` to get input. Sound like it shouldn't happen in a synchronous bit of code? Well, think of it this way: the console goes on working whether you tell it to or not.

Here's a quick example of something that could go wrong. You write a message to the console telling the user to keep hands away from the keyboard:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please don't type anything for 2 seconds.");
```

Good. Now that the user isn't going to mess up anything, you can do your work for 2 seconds, expecting no user input:

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;

while (DateTime.Now < startTime.AddSeconds(2)) ;
```

Okay, *now* we're ready for some input:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value.");
var inputVal = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("The value entered was: " + inputVal);
```

Works great. But wait, what if Johnny User ignores the warning, and types "100" then hits the "Enter" key before 2 seconds is elapsed? In that case, it is all recorded by the Console, and dutifully passed to `Console.ReadLine()` when that line of code is reached... **after the input has occurred from the user.**